# Create POIs to review

Tags: fiware, fiware-poi

I want to create POIs that need to be reviewed by someone authorized before
who is not authorized users can see the POI. Also when updating
or delete a point.

I do not know if it can be done natively or there is some strategy that is being followed in these cases.

Any advice or suggestion is welcome.

Regards.

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. Please show your research and what actions you have taken to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Our recommendation is to use the FIWARE context Broker to deal with POIs. An NGSI Data Model for POIs is available at

http://fiware-datamodels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PointOfInterest/PointOfInterest/doc/spec/index.html

I hope this helps